# adding multiple canvas's using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have the following controller code:

```
new Layer('<canvas id="layer1" width="450" height="631" class="imageElement" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0; border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>');

$scope.layerContainer = document.getElementById('layerContainer');

$scope.layers = [$scope.canvas];

//layer object
function Layer(element) {
    this.canvas = element;
}
```

and the following html:

```
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="width: 450px; height: 631px;">
    <div style="position: relative;" id="layerContainer" ng-repeat="layer in layers" ng-bind-html-unsafe="layer.canvas" >

    </div>
</div>
```

however when running this nothing is shown (the class 'imageElement' has the following css:

```
   .imageElement{
    background-image: url("../resources/billede.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

)

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing a `$scope.canvas =` before `new Layer('<canvas...`

If you add that assignment, your code should work.